# Дана матрица A порядка n. Расставьте элементы строк с четными номерами матрицы в порядке убывания

Tags: java

не знаю, как можно расставить элементы, вот мой кусочек кода, помогите пожалуйста.

```
int [][] matrix= new int[3][4];

Random rn=new Random();


    for(int i=0;i<matrix.length;i++)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<matrix[i].length;j++)
        {
           matrix[i][j]=rn.nextInt(10)+1;


        }

    }

    for(int i=0;i<matrix.length;i++)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<matrix[i].length;j++)
        {
            if(matrix[i][j]%2==0)
            {
                ///?????
            }




        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[][] matrix = new int[3][4];

    Random rn = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = rn.nextInt(10) + 1;
        }
    }

    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
            if (matrix[i][j] % 2 == 0) {
                list.add(matrix[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }

    list.sort(Collections.reverseOrder());        
    System.out.println(list);

}
```